# Как сделать скачивание CSV-файла при нажатии по ссылке, а не открытие его в браузере?

Tags: php

На сайте для скачивания CSV-файла используется ссылка http://sitename.ru/file.csv. И при нажатии на ссылку файл не скачивается, а открывается в браузере. Как можно сделать, чтобы файл сразу скачивался без открытия в браузере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылайся на PHP файл, назови скажем getcsv.php

```
<a href="getcsv.php">Скачать CSV</a>
```

А там:

```
<?php

$filename = 'simple.csv';

header("Content-type: application/x-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
readfile($filename);

?>
```

Comment: Переделал немного, добавил readfile, а то пустой качался :)