# скачивание файла по ссылке

Tags: php, html

Отправляется почта через `php (main())`, в тексте сообщения есть ссылка такого вида:

```
<a href="$url/filename.txt">скачать</a>
```

То есть прямая ссылка к файлу, при нажатии нужно файл скачивать,а не открывать в браузере. 
Заголовки передавать не могу.

Comment: А отправить файл вместе с письмом?

Comment: файл может быть большим, и что бы гемора не было, файл лежит на нашем сервере.

Comment: Если вы вставляете ссылку, она в любом случае будет открываться браузером

Answer (score 1):

**Для html**

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

Можно использовать функцию `copy` для php если это нужно делать внутри на сервере

```
<?php
$url='http://someserver21973892798/file.html'; 
if(!copy($url,__DIR__.'/newfile.html')){
echo "не удалось скопировать ...\n";
}
```

обязательно нужно указать название нового файла `/newfile.html` (к примеру) и рекомендую использовать абсолютный путь который получаем волшебной константой `__DIR__`. В `$url` используйте ваш путь к файлу который нужно закачать на ваш сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить к ссылке парамерт download:

```
<a href="file.pdf" download>скачать</a>
```

можно задать имя сохраняемого файла:

```
<a href="file.pdf" download="filename">скачать</a>
```

Но работает не во всех браузерах.

Comment: (могу комментировать только тут) вот еще вариант решения: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263588/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83